# how to modify or insert where into expression tree

Tags: linq, where-clause, expression-trees

by default I have this:

```cs
Expression<Func<ItemGroup, ItemGroupView>> Exp = 
    m => new ItemGroupView{
        ID = m.id,
        Name = m.name,
        TotalCount = m.groupDetail.Sum(n => n.item.itemDetail.Count())
    };
```

but in the runtime, I might want to add multiple filter. So for example, if I specify the status to 1 and category to mineral then it becomes

```cs
Expression<Func<ItemGroup, ItemGroupView>> Exp = 
    m => new ItemGroupView{
        ID = m.id,
        Name = m.name,
        TotalCount = m.groupDetail.Sum(
            n => n.item.itemDetail
            .Where(o => o.status == 1 && o.category == "mineral")
            .Count())
    };

// ItemGroup.groupDetail is collection of ItemGroupDetail (n)
// ItemGroupDetail.item is Item
// Item.itemDetail is collection of ItemDetail  (o)
// ItemDetail.item is Item
```

how do I modify the expression tree to insert multiple `Where` dynamically?

So far I do the default like this

```cs
private int _status;
private string _category;

internal Expression<Func<ItemDetail, bool>> whereStatus()
{
    return o => o.status == _status;
}

internal Expression<Func<ItemDetail, bool>> whereCategory()
{
    return o => o.category == _category ;
}

internal Expression<Func<ItemGroup, ItemGroupView>> GetEx()
{
    return m => new ItemGroupView{
        ID = m.id,
        Name = m.name,
        TotalCount = m.groupDetail.Sum(n => n.item.itemDetail.Count())
    };
}

internal IQueryable<ItemGroupView> GetSelectQuery(IQueryabe<ItemGroup> ie)
{
    ParameterExpression m = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ItemGroup), "m");
    ParameterExpression n = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ItemGroupDetail), "n");

    MemberInitExpression ex = (MemberInitExpression)GetEx().Body;

   // ParameterReplacer is inherited from ExpressionVisitor
    ex = (MemberInitExpression)new ParameterReplacer(
        new ParameterExpression[] { m, n }).Visit(ex);

    // ? ? ? ?  
    // how to modify the Expression if _status or _category is supplied?

    Expression<Func<ItemGroup, ItemGroupView>> el =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<ItemGroup, ItemGroupView>>
                    (ex, new ParameterExpression { m });

    return ie.Select(el);
}
```

EDIT:
ItemGroup.itemDetail changed to ItemGroup.groupDetail, to avoid confusion between groups and items..

Answer (score 0):

If you can create an expression that represents the `Where()` operation, you can then paste it into your main expression using [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx):

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<ItemDetail>, IQueryable<ItemDetail>>> whereExpression=
    id => id.Where(o => o.status == 1 && o.category == "mineral");

Expression<Func<ItemGroup, ItemGroupView>> Exp =
    m => new ItemGroupView
    {
        ID = m.id,
        Name = m.name,
        TotalCount =
            whereExpression.Invoke(m.itemDetail)
                .Sum(n => n.item.itemDetail.Count())
    };
Exp = Exp.Expand();
```

(Don't forget that last line, it's important.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check it out.. but I think I'll try to modify the expression tree first..

Comment: @sickdoctor I don't see any reason why you would want to do that. Modifying expressions is not that simpler, because they're immutable. If you want to do it anyway, have a look at `ExpressionVisitor`.